# Why my html element is not being hidden even after overflow:hidden property

Tags: html, css, dom, css-animations

I have created an animated title area. When I hover over my logo area, I am animating my first text to move up out of view and the second one to come into view. The animation is working perfectly.

However, when it's not in hover mode, the second text which is below is not being hidden. I have set the logo container as overflow: hidden, but it's still not hidden.

Here is my HTML: -

```css
nav{
  background: #05251F;
  min-height: 70px;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
  color: whitesmoke;

}

.nav-container{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo-container{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-container .logo-container h2{
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}

.nav-container .logo-container:hover .first{
  transform: translateY(-120%);
}

.nav-container .logo-container:hover .second{
  transform: translateY(-120%);
}

h1{
  font-family: headingFontRegular;
}

nav .nav-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0px 30px;
}

nav .nav-container h2{
  margin:10px;
}

nav .nav-container ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-container">
      <div class="logo-container">
          <h2 class="first">Ajay Birbal.</h2>
          <h2 class="second">Ajay Birbal.</h2>
      </div>
      <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Blog</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your `.logo-container` does not have any height restriction, it is allowed to grow as high as its content demands, and therefor there _is_ no “overflow” that could be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `height` in `.logo-container`

```css
nav{
  background: #05251F;
  min-height: 70px;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
  color: whitesmoke;

}

.nav-container{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo-container{
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 70px; // Added
}

.nav-container .logo-container h2{
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  line-height: 2; // Added
}

.nav-container .logo-container:hover .first{
  transform: translateY(-120%);
}

.nav-container .logo-container:hover .second{
  transform: translateY(-120%);
}

h1{
  font-family: headingFontRegular;
}

nav .nav-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0px 30px;
}

nav .nav-container h2{
  margin:10px;
}

nav .nav-container ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-container">
      <div class="logo-container">
          <h2 class="first">Ajay Birbal.</h2>
          <h2 class="second">Ajay Birbal.</h2>
      </div>
      <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Blog</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nav{
  background: #05251F;
  min-height: 70px;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
  color: whitesmoke;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

You need to set overflow in the .nav element